# List sharepoint 2010 sites that uses managed metadata

Tags: sharepoint-2010, metadata, powershell-4.0

Here is the case:
We have 390 site collections, where we want to know if they use managed metadata or not due to a migration that is happening this authum.

If they do, we have no idea what termset etc they would be using.

Googeling, I can'f find much about on how to approch this.

I assume this can be done with Powershell.
It's a Sharepoint 2010 farm.

What I need is bascily:

Url:                           Managed MetaData
https:test.com/sites/test      Yes
https:test.com/sites/tes2      No

If doing this with powershell, we would have the list of sites in a .txt file the script would read, as over 20000 site collections exist and we are only intrested in the 390.

Anyone who done this who can provide some links or help?

Comment: Check this out
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/57003/how-to-find-out-if-and-if-possible-how-often-a-term-is-used

Answer (score 0):

Iterating every site collection, you should find you way with such [script](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23494.sharepoint-use-powershell-to-find-fields-using-a-managed-metadata-termset.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

How I did it is that the hidden list, "TaxonomyHiddenList" contains items if the site uses it, so I made a script to have a look if the there was any and put true or false in the output depending on use.

```
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -erroraction silentlycontinue

$sites = Get-Content sites.txt $listname = "TaxonomyHiddenList" $result = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()

if(!(Test-Path ".\hiddenlist.csv")) {
    "Site;ListItem" | Out-File -FilePath ".\hiddenlist.csv" }

foreach ($site in $sites) {
    $subsites = ((Get-SPWeb $site).Site).allwebs | Where-Object {$_.url -like "$site*"}

    foreach($subsite in $subsites)
    {
        $web = Get-SPWeb $site
        $list1 = $web.Lists | where{$_.Title -eq $listname}

        if($list1.ItemCount -gt 0)
        {
            $result.Add("$($subsite.Url);true")
        }
        else
        {
            $result.Add("$($subsite.Url);false")
        }
    } }

$result | Out-File -FilePath ".\hiddenlist.csv" -Append
```